# How to stop container when all the partitions are paused?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a use case where I am creating dynamic listeners based on API calls. After receiving a certain message, I am pausing the partition individually. For example, If I received a message with offset 100, then that partition will be paused. And this will be done for all partitions.
After all the partitions are paused, I want to stop the container.

This is my code -

```
public class OffsetBasedMessageListener implements ConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, String> {

  @Override
  public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
    if (consumerRecord.offset() == 100) {
    consumer.pause(Collections.singleton(new TopicPartition(consumerRecord.topic(),
    consumerRecord.partition())));
  }
}
```

Now, I have an EventListener configured which will be triggered when the container is Idle.

```
  @EventListener
  public void onIdle(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    Collection<TopicPartition> collection = event.getContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class).getAssignedPartitions();
    for (TopicPartition topicPartition: collection) {
      System.out.println(

event.getContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class).isPartitionPaused(topicPartition));
        }
      }
```

So, what I am doing now is checking if all partitions are paused then I'll stop the container. But `isPartitionPaused` always returns false, even though it should return true.

I am using SpringBoot with SpringKafka.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? or Is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pause the consumer directly - the container doesn't know that you have paused it; hence it returns false.

Call `pausePartition` on the container instead.

Note that either way, the consumer won't actually pause until all the records from the previous poll are processed. Set `max.poll.records` to 1 to pause immediately.

**EDIT**

This works just fine for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class So67430862Application {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So67430862Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67430862Application.class, args);
    }

    Set<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> containers = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    int id;

    @Autowired
    Creator creator;

    @PostMapping(path = "/send/{topic}")
    public void sendFoo(@PathVariable String topic) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = this.creator.create(topic);
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("group" + ++id);
        container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(new Listener(container));
        this.containers.add(container);
        container.start();
    }

    @EventListener
    public void idle(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container =
                event.getContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class);
        if (this.containers.contains(container)) {
            boolean allPaused = container.getAssignedPartitions()
                    .stream()
                    .map(part -> container.isPartitionPaused(part))
                    .allMatch(paused -> paused);
            LOG.info("All paused? {}", allPaused);
            if (allPaused) {
                container.stop(() -> { });
                this.containers.remove(container);
            }
        }
    }

//  @Bean
//  public NewTopic topic() {
//      return TopicBuilder.name("so67430862").partitions(5).replicas(1).build();
//  }
//
//
//  @Bean
//  public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
//      return args -> {
//          IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(p -> {
//              IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i ->template.send("so67430862", p, null, "test"));
//          });
//      };
//  }

}

@Component
class Creator {

    private final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory;

    Creator(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> create(String topic) {
        return this.factory.createContainer(topic);
    }

}

class Listener extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware implements MessageListener<String, String> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);

    final ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container;

    Listener(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> data) {
        LOG.info(ListenerUtils.recordToString(data, true));
        if (data.offset() == 5) {
            LOG.info("Pausing partition {}", data.partition());
            this.container.pausePartition(new TopicPartition(data.topic(), data.partition()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        callback.seekToBeginning(assignments.keySet());
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=1
spring.kafka.listener.idle-event-interval=5000
```

```
2021-05-10 11:51:15.792  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-0@0
2021-05-10 11:51:15.797  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-0@1
2021-05-10 11:51:15.799  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-0@2
2021-05-10 11:51:15.801  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-0@3
2021-05-10 11:51:15.803  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-0@4
2021-05-10 11:51:15.809  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-0@5
2021-05-10 11:51:15.809  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : Pausing partition 0
2021-05-10 11:51:15.814  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-1@0
2021-05-10 11:51:15.816  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-1@1
2021-05-10 11:51:15.819  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-1@2
2021-05-10 11:51:15.823  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-1@3
2021-05-10 11:51:15.828  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-1@4
2021-05-10 11:51:15.831  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-1@5
2021-05-10 11:51:15.831  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : Pausing partition 1
2021-05-10 11:51:15.835  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-4@0
2021-05-10 11:51:15.838  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-4@1
2021-05-10 11:51:15.841  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-4@2
2021-05-10 11:51:15.844  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-4@3
2021-05-10 11:51:15.846  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-4@4
2021-05-10 11:51:15.849  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-4@5
2021-05-10 11:51:15.850  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : Pausing partition 4
2021-05-10 11:51:15.854  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-2@0
2021-05-10 11:51:15.858  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-2@1
2021-05-10 11:51:15.861  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-2@2
2021-05-10 11:51:15.864  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-2@3
2021-05-10 11:51:15.866  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-2@4
2021-05-10 11:51:15.871  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-2@5
2021-05-10 11:51:15.871  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : Pausing partition 2
2021-05-10 11:51:15.875  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-3@0
2021-05-10 11:51:15.877  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-3@1
2021-05-10 11:51:15.880  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-3@2
2021-05-10 11:51:15.883  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-3@3
2021-05-10 11:51:15.886  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-3@4
2021-05-10 11:51:15.889  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : so67430862-3@5
2021-05-10 11:51:15.889  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.Listener                : Pausing partition 3
2021-05-10 11:51:20.893  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So67430862Application   : All paused? true
2021-05-10 11:51:20.895  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group1-1, groupId=group1] Revoke previously assigned partitions so67430862-0, so67430862-1, so67430862-4, so67430862-2, so67430862-3
2021-05-10 11:51:20.895  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : group1: partitions revoked: [so67430862-0, so67430862-1, so67430862-4, so67430862-2, so67430862-3]
2021-05-10 11:51:20.895  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group1-1, groupId=group1] Member consumer-group1-1-be137c2c-2bbf-4235-a143-15d33a0cfe52 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to the consumer unsubscribed from all topics
2021-05-10 11:51:20.896  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group1-1, groupId=group1] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2021-05-10 11:51:20.896  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService
2021-05-10 11:51:20.897  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2021-05-10 11:51:20.897  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2021-05-10 11:51:20.898  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2021-05-10 11:51:20.901  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-group1-1 unregistered
2021-05-10 11:51:20.902  INFO 58682 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : group1: Consumer stopped
```

The commented out code creates a topic with 5 partitions and 10 records in each; the listener pauses each partition at offset 5. As you can see we don't get the rest of the records.

Comment: How can I access the container in the `onMessage` function?

Comment: You don’t seem to be using @KafkaListener so you must have declared it as a bean. I don’t think you can auto wire it because you will get circular references. You can auto wire the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry and call getAllListenerContainers() and iterate over them. Or implement ApplicationContextAware and get the bean by name from the context.

Comment: Through `KafkaaListenerEndpointRegistry`, I am only getting containers that are static. The dynamic listeners are not present in `getAllListenerContainers`

Comment: Also, I tried circular reference, but isPartitionPaused is still returning false, even though I paused it using the container.

Comment: It won’t actually pause until the listener exits.

Comment: How to exit a listener?

Comment: Also, my max poll records config is 1 but still `pausePartition` consumes messages after pausing